# How does a comma followed by a variable assignment concatenate?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am still in the early stages of learning Python and came accross this syntax but I have no idea what it does.

```
check, expression = expression, expression.replace('()', '').replace('[]', '').replace('{}', '')
```

Now I know what the str.replace() function does, I am just unclear in how in the end is "check" being assigned to this concatenation of replace functions.

**Context:**

Here is the full code for context, the purpose of it is just to check wether brackets are being used correctly in a given string:

```
BRACKETS = ("{","[","(","}","]",")")
list = []

#Creating a list with only the brackets in it.
for c in expression:
    if (c in BRACKETS) and (c in expression):
        list.append(c)

expression = ''.join(list)

while expression:
    check, expression = expression, expression.replace('()', '').replace('[]', '').replace('{}', '')
    if expression == check:
        return False
return True
```

Comment: The value of `expression` is assigned to `check`, while the value of `expression.replace...` is assigned to `expression`. For example, if you do `a, b = 1, 2`, then a gets 1 and b gets 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example:

```
a = 'a'
b = 'b'

temp = a
a = b
b = temp

print(a) # 'b'
print(b) # 'a'
```

From this, it can be seen that the three lines in the middle swap the values of `a` and `b`. In Python, tuple packing and unpacking can be used in order to eliminate the need for the temporary variable.

```
a = 'a'
b = 'b'

temp_tuple = b, a # tuple packing
print(temp_tuple) # ('b', 'a')

a, b = temp_tuple # tuple unpacking
print(a) # 'b'
print(b) # 'a'
```

Now, we can combine this packing and unpacking into a single expression.

```
a = 'a'
b = 'b'

a, b = b, a

print(a) # 'b'
print(b) # 'a'
```

You code saves the original value of `expression` into `check` and saves the updated version of `expression` back into `expression`. It then compares the two variables to see whether `expression` was changed by all the `replace` calls.

**Edit:** Regarding the comment about whether Python goes through the code segment three times, we can use to `dis` module to disassemble the Python bytecode for a test function.

```
from dis import dis

def test(expression):
    while expression:
        check, expression = expression, expression.replace('()', '').replace('[]', '').replace('{}', '')
        if expression == check:
            return False
    return True

print dis(test)
```

This prints the following (with some annotations):

```
# while expression:
4           0 SETUP_LOOP              75 (to 78)
      >>    3 LOAD_FAST                0 (expression)   # start
            6 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       77                # jump to exit

# check, expression = [...]
5           9 LOAD_FAST                0 (expression)
           12 LOAD_FAST                0 (expression)
           15 LOAD_ATTR                0 (replace)
           18 LOAD_CONST               1 ('()')
           21 LOAD_CONST               2 ('')
           24 CALL_FUNCTION            2
           27 LOAD_ATTR                0 (replace)
           30 LOAD_CONST               3 ('[]')
           33 LOAD_CONST               2 ('')
           36 CALL_FUNCTION            2
           39 LOAD_ATTR                0 (replace)
           42 LOAD_CONST               4 ('{}')
           45 LOAD_CONST               2 ('')
           48 CALL_FUNCTION            2
           51 ROT_TWO             
           52 STORE_FAST               1 (check)
           55 STORE_FAST               0 (expression)

# if check == expression:
6          58 LOAD_FAST                0 (expression)
           61 LOAD_FAST                1 (check)
           64 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
           67 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        3                # jump to start

# return False
7          70 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (False)
           73 RETURN_VALUE        
           74 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            3                # jump to start
      >>   77 POP_BLOCK                                 # exit

# return True
8     >>   78 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (True)
           81 RETURN_VALUE
```

From this it can be seen that the following occurs:

1. `expression` is loaded and checked for its truthiness. If `True`, the loop immediately exits.
2. The values of `check` and `expression` are loaded, updated, swapped, and stored.
3. The value of `check` is compared to that of `expression`. If `False`, the loop jumps to the start. Otherwise, `False` is returned.
4. The value of `True` is returned. This will only occur if the loop exited because the value of  `expression` was not truthy in the first step.

I think that the only real thing to note in the `check, expression = [...]` line is the use of the instruction `ROT_TWO`, which [swaps the two top-most stack items.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-ROT_TWO) On line 9, the value of `expression` is loaded. On lines 12-48, the value of `expression` loaded and updated, pushing the value loaded on line 9 back in the stack. Then, on line 51, these two values are swapped.

Comment: Does that mean that python runs through that segment of code three times? Once to assign the original value of `expression` into `check` and to save the updated version of `expression` back into `expression`. A second to compare the if `expression` was changed, and a last one to save the update version of `expression` into `check` ?

Answer (score 1):

The line you're asking about is equivalent to:

```
check      = expression
expression = expression.replace('()', '').replace('[]', '').replace('{}', '')
```

Python allows multiple assignments with a single `=`. Each variable on the left side is assigned a corresponding value from the right side.

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**

For example:

```
x, y = 1, 2
```

`x` will be initialized with 1 & `y` be initialized with 2.

You can also use this to unwrap tuples. For e.g

```
>>> def foo(): return 1, 2
>>> x = foo()
>>> x  # It is tuple
(1, 2)   
>>> x, y = foo()  # Value of 'x' is 1 and 'y' is 2
>>> x
1
>>> y
2
```

You can also use this to swap two numbers as `a, b = b, a`